# npm install clear the react-native in node_modules

Tags: react-native, npm, redux, npm-install

I face with a problem when try to use `npm install` to install `redux` to my `react-native` project. Any time I do run `npm install redux --save` the `react-native` directory inside `node_modules` will be cleared.

Then I use `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` the all `react-native` package does not install inside `node_modules` so I must re-create project.

I also try to copy & past `react-redux` and `redux` in `node_modules` from another project to my current `react-native` project. But it can't success, the error lead me to the [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968) on github. I followed this help and it also fail.

Some other information:

➜  npm: 5.0.3

➜  react-native-cli: 2.0.1

➜  react-native: 0.45.0

➜  package.json

```
{
    "name": "MyProjectNAME",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "0.45.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
        "redux": "^3.6.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-es2017": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.2",
        "jest": "20.0.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

Any suggest is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Glad you have solved this issue using a workaround way but please allow me to explain why react-native module was removed when you ran `npm install redux --save`.

**Solution:**

1. Move the package-lock.json out of the project folder (Don't delete it yet because you will need to inspect it later on)
2. Run `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
3. Check the /node_modules and react-native should be there now
4. Run `npm install redux` (npm v5 will --save by default) to install redux without having existing modules get removed

**What is package-lock.json?**

There are a bunch of changes for npm v5 which you can read it [here](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/161081169345/v500). One of them is generating package-lock.json (lockfile) whenever npm modifies /node_modules or package.json.

With package-lock.json, anyone who runs `npm install` (v5) will get the exact same node_modules tree that you were developing on. So, you would have to commit this file too.

**Why react-native module and others were removed after running `npm install somePackageName` even they are defined in the package.json?**

The removal happened because of your existing node modules were installed prior to npm v5. If you use npm v5 to install a module (e.g. `npm install redux`), you will notice three things:

1. package-lock.json will be generated (or updated if exists). Redux and its dependencies are saved into it.
2. The redux's package.json is different than node modules that were installed prior to npm v5 (some extra fields prefix with _ e.g. _from, _requiredBy, _resolved etc.).
3. Finally, any module installed prior to v5 will be removed which I guess due to the missing extra fields in its package.json **AND** does not exist in the newly generated package-lock.json.

So, running `rm -rf node_modules && npm install` again will not solve the issue because of the package-lock.json file (Remember only redux and its dependencies were saved to the file? You can check the old package-lock.json)

Hope this might help someone else.

Comment: @hwd Glad that it helps

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem by 2 steps:

1) Create a reactjs project and install redux

2) Copy all content of `node_modules` in step 1 and paste to my current `react-native` project.

Reload app. Everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

It gets removed if you create app using yarn. If you have created the app using yarn please run yarn add react-redux instead of npm install react-redux