# react-native: command not found, tried several solutions, none worked

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, npm-install

I'm working on an ancient react native project, it was absolutely working, then when I wanted to continue working on it, I had this problem,

[image]

This is the package.json file.
[image]

I ve tried this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472878/npm-install-clear-the-react-native-in-node-modules/44476694#44476694), deleting the package-lock.json file and re executing

> npm install

but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo npm uninstall -g react-native-cli` and then `sudo npm install -g react-native-cli`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCronemberger Thank you, it  actually works for me. Have a nice day mate.

Comment: No problem, you too

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to uninstall react-native-cli gloabally with

> sudo npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

and than install it globally

> sudo npm insatll -g react-native-cli

and now it works perfectly :)